# Need help in pattern matching in Java for multiple braces

Tags: java, regex

I need a pattern matching string that extracts speed ex(15.0) in to second group of pattern matching and rest of the string in to first group from following strings:

1. Ananatapur, ATP (15.0)
2. Kurnool KNL (25.0)
3. Hyderabad, HYD (Telangana) (100.0)
4. Vijayawada, BZA, South (10.0)
5. Goa Smith (STL Terminal) (15.0)
6. Canada, NJ, Pavonia (SA) (15.0)
7. Cyber City Mixing Center, MO (15.0)
8. Stacking Heights, MI (SA) (15.0)

Can any one please help me regarding the same?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried...

Comment: I had to split the given string in to two groups. The one containing the 15.0 in one group and the rest in to other using pattern matching. I hope this clarifies what I am asking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex for matching:

```
^([^)]+\))\s+\(([^)]+)\)
```

And use group #1 and group #2.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tI8gF2/1)

**Java regex:**

```
Patter p = Pattern.compile( "^([^)]+\\))\\s+\\(([^)]+)\\)" );
```

#### Explanation:

```
^         - start of the string
([^)]+\)) - 1st Capturing group ([^)]+\)). [^)]+\) matches anything but ) followed by a )
\s+\(     - Match 1 or more white-spaces followed by (
([^)]+)   - 2nd Capturing group ([^)]+). [^)]+\) matches anything but )
\)        - Match lliteral )
```

Comment: Can you please explain me the above pattern @anubhava

Comment: If you check demo link, there is pretty good explanation on right hand side panel. Once you go through this let me know what specific question you have and I will answer it here.

Comment: I have also added a brief explanation in my answer.

Comment: @Raj: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: facing more issues as I go deep in to the loop in my scenario. Actually first i am capturing some values and put them in first array. In second I need to fetch the same values from other page, here speed is getting amended to the names. The possible combination of all names are in this pattern:

Comment: Observe some has one comma, two commas, one bracket and two brackets, no commas etc. I need a pattern that capture the value in last bracket i.e.ex (15) in second group of pattern matching and the rest of the string(irrespective of no of commas and brackets present)in first group. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: To clarify this requirement can you edit the question with some examples.

Comment: changed the question to include all type of strings according to your suggestion. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: [Will this regex work for you](https://regex101.com/r/tI8gF2/2)